# After extracting files with 7zip how can you rename those file and save

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ksh, 7zip

I am using the following command to extract the files with 7zip

```
7za x -p$passwd $file -o$outdir
```

there are many files getting extracted, i want to rename these files after extraction how can i do it with help of writing a script in `ksh`

```
files=`ls ABC_0722*.zip | xargs -r`
outdir="/abc/def/prq/xyz"
for file in $files; do
    passwd=`echo $file| awk '{print substr($0,11,2)}'``echo ABC``echo $file| awk '{print substr($0,5,2)}'`
    7za x -p$passwd $file -o$outdir        
done
```

After the extraction I need to rename the files to `abcdef`.

Comment: What are the filenames? What do you want to rename them to? Can you post what you've already tried?

Comment: I think you cannot have more than one file with the same name in a directory of a Linux system.

Comment: not the same name but abcdef1,abcdef2,abcdef3 etc

Comment: Look at the `rename` command on your system.  There are a couple of versions around; the powerful one uses Perl regular expressions.  The renaming is completely independent of the `7zip`/`7za`; it would be the same if you'd use `tar` or `ncftp` indeed just downloaded the files one at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After decompress all files, use a `for` loop looking for all normal files that are not symbolink links, replace the basename of the path and replace it with `abcde` plus a counter:

```
for f in $outdir/*; do 
    [[ -f $f && ! -L $f ]] && { ((++i)); mv -- "$f" "${f%/*}/abcde$i"; }; 
done
```